# JUnit Error how do I fix this?

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors

So when I run JUnit testing on Calculator.class which is compiled in build/main/package together with the test class CalculatorTest.java compiled in build/main/package it gives me this error.

```
test:
    [junit] Running CalculatorTest
    [junit] Testsuite: CalculatorTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 se
c
    [junit]
    [junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
    [junit] CalculatorTest (wrong name: package/CalculatorTest)
    [junit] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CalculatorTest (wrong name: package/C
alculatorTest)
```

When I run JUnit testing without the "package ;" inside both java file it doesnt give me any error instead it gives me the "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" message without any errors.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your project setup in your IDE. Hard to debug via Stack Overflow. Have you got a local you could ask?

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that the package declaration at the top of your test class is not the same as the folder hierarchy to which you compile it to.

For instance this won't work if I compile a class with a package declaration like below  to /build :

```
package org.foo.bar
```

The easy way to fix this is to have both your classes in the same package

Comment: So it would be better if I declare " package bar  " to both Calculator and CalculatorTest?

Comment: You could: put the same package declaration for each class, then compile them to the same folder according to your package name.